# Find out how many uncommitted items are in the session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I developed an application which parses a lot of data, but if I commit the data after parsing all the data, it will consume too much memory. However, I cannot commit it each time, because it costs too much hard disk I/O.

Therefore, my question is how can I know how many uncommitted items are in the session?

Comment: We will need way more information to help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of uncommitted changes using `session.new`, `session.dirty` and `session.deleted`, **in combination with** tracking flushes (which cause .new, .dirty and .deleted to be reset) via the events system. See the conversation here for more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/eGxpQBChXQw

Answer (score 2):

You can use [session.new](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.new). It's a collection of just created and uncommited objects. Also [session.dirty](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty) can be useful. To quote the docs:

```
# pending objects recently added to the Session
session.new

# persistent objects which currently have changes detected
# (this collection is now created on the fly each time the property is called)
session.dirty

# persistent objects that have been marked as deleted via session.delete(obj)
session.deleted

# dictionary of all persistent objects, keyed on their
# identity key
session.identity_map
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's helpful!!

Comment: It seems that `session.new`, `session.dirty` and `session.deleted` are all the **unflushed** instances, not uncommitted. This means that if you manually flush the session (or it flushes automatically), these attributes do NOT reflect the uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of buffering. Try a reasonably large chunk and reduce it if there's too much disk I/O (or you don't like it causing long pauses, etc) or increase it if your profile shows too much CPU time in I/O calls.

To implement, use an array, each "write" you append an item to the array. Have a separate "flush" function that writes the whole thing. Each append you check, and if it has reached maximum size, write them all, and clear the array. At the end, call the flush function to write partially filled array.